# Save Chart view as image to Camera roll or any other path?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

When click the button, I want to save barChartView as an image to the Photos app or any other path.

I have tried the following;

```
@IBAction func saveChart(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {  
    myBarChartView.saveToCameraRoll()  // for save into photos app
}
```

Also tried the same func with the below line to save into other paths:

```
@IBAction func saveChart(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {  
    myBarChartView.saveToPath(path: String, format: 
    ChartViewBase.ImageFormat, compressionQuality: Double)  // for save into other path
}
```

Both of them show an error as 'BarChart has no member 'Save to camera roll' and 'saveToPath' respectively.

What should I use to save my Chart into image file?

Comment: The question is properly tagged with `ios-charts`, so I'd venture it's a `BarChartView`.

Answer (score 0):

That format was removed with version 3.0. There's now just one format:

```
let result = barChartView.save(to: "<path_to>/chart.png", format: BarLineChartViewBase.ImageFormat.png, compressionQuality: 1.0)
```